# Trying to encrypt a string using my private key in iOS gives me a -4 error

Tags: ios, encryption

I'm not an expert about this at all, so I've found a wrapper on github called RSA and tried to use it.
What I need to do is simply encrypt a string using my private key.

This is the method used to do the encryption:

```
- (NSString *)rsaEncryptWithData:(NSData*)data usingPublicKey:(BOOL)yes {
    if (yes) {
        [self getKeyRefFor:publicTag];
    } else {
        [self getKeyRefFor:privateTag];
    }
}
SecKeyRef key = self.publicKeyRef;
size_t cipherBufferSize = SecKeyGetBlockSize(key);
uint8_t *cipherBuffer = malloc(cipherBufferSize * sizeof(uint8_t));
memset((void *)cipherBuffer, 0*0, cipherBufferSize);

NSData *plainTextBytes = data;
size_t blockSize = cipherBufferSize - 11;
size_t blockCount = (size_t)ceil([plainTextBytes length] / (double)blockSize);
NSMutableData *encryptedData = [NSMutableData dataWithCapacity:0];

for (int i=0; i<blockCount; i++) {

    int bufferSize = (int)MIN(blockSize,[plainTextBytes length] - i * blockSize);
    NSData *buffer = [plainTextBytes subdataWithRange:NSMakeRange(i * blockSize, bufferSize)];

    OSStatus status = SecKeyEncrypt(key,
                                    kSecPaddingPKCS1,
                                    (const uint8_t *)[buffer bytes],
                                    [buffer length],
                                    cipherBuffer,
                                    &cipherBufferSize);

    if (status == noErr){
        NSData *encryptedBytes = [NSData dataWithBytes:(const void *)cipherBuffer length:cipherBufferSize];
        [encryptedData appendData:encryptedBytes];

    }else{

        if (cipherBuffer) {
            free(cipherBuffer);
        }
        return nil;
    }
}
if (cipherBuffer) free(cipherBuffer);

return [encryptedData base64EncodedStringWithOptions:0];
}
```

If I use my public key to encrypt, everything is working fine, but if I try to use my private key then the OSStatus variable returns a -4 (Function or operation not implemented.).

Any help would be really appreciated, since I really don't know what to do.

Thanks.

Comment: You're not supposed to encrypt with the private key. That's what the public key is for. The private key can be used to generate a signature which can be verified with the public key; but this is different from encryption.

Comment: Actually what I wanted to do is generate a signature with my private key. can I do it using this wrapper or do I need something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using the [MIHCrypto](https://github.com/hohl/MIHCrypto) framework to create a key pair and to sign my messages.
Is this easy:

```
- (NSData *)signMessageData:(NSData *)data withKey:(MIHRSAPrivateKey *)privKey {
    NSError *signingError = nil;
    NSData *signatureData = [privKey signWithSHA256:data error:&signingError];
    if (signingError != nil) {
        NSLog(@"Error: %@", signingError.localizedDescription);
    }
    return signatureData;
}
```